# (XPages)How to get the documentID or open the corresponding detailed information page?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, xpages, ojdbc

When you click on PONUM, you will be taken to another page.

The content of this page is the detailed information of the PONUM.

How to connect and correspond?

The key line is in the ">><<"

The current program is as follows:

```
var temp = new ojdbc.ConnOracle113;

if(!temp.ConnectDB()){
    return "Can't connect the Oracle "
}else{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM CB4_AUCTION where ORDER_FLAG='1'";
    var res:java.sql.ResultSet = temp.SelectSQL(sql);
    if(res != null){//
        var t = "";
        t = "<table id=\"auction\" style=\"font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;width:100%;overflow:auto;white-space:nowrap;\" border=\"1\"><tr><th>PONUM</th><th>COMP</th><th>CASENAME</th><th>CASESTATUS</th></tr>"
        while(res.next()){
            t = t + "<tr style=\"font-size:12pt;\">";
            >>t = t + "<td>" + "<a href='https://fcpnotest1.feg.com.tw/ArielTes.nsf/C00B4_01_1.xsp' target='_blank' style='color:#0000FF;'>" + res.getString("PONUM") + "</a>" + "</td>";<<
            t = t + "<td>" + res.getString("PUR_COMP_NAME") + "</td>";
            t = t + "<td>" + res.getString("AUCTIONNAME") + "</td>";
            if (res.getDouble("ORDER_FLAG") == '1'){
                t = t + "<td>" + "NUll" + "</td>";
            }
        }
        t = t + "</table>";
        return t;
    }else{
        return "Oracle no data！";
    }
    temp.CloseAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append the PONUM to the URL, using '&ponum=', and then collect the PONUM from the URL on the XPage, and use it to do the lookup into the database.

Comment: Sorry.....Can you give me an example to try? I still don't know how to write the code.